# XCode - Internal Error when starting a specific project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, internal

It first happend, when I changed something with the .xib-File and somehow I cannot find anything similiar (enough) on the internet that might help. And of course I did try turning it off and on again!

More details from the alert window I got:

Internal Error

File: /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1691/pbxindex/PBXProjectIndex.m 
Line: 6266 
Object: 
Method: _locationForNewFileRecords:

Assertion failed: headHeader && headHeader->type == PBXSymFreeBlock

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution sounds a bit odd but try this:

1. Clean all Targets in XCode
2. Close XCode
3. Restart your Mac
4. Try to build your app again

Comment: That easy, huh? I guess I was already worring so much about my working project, that I didn't thought of cleaning all targets, so thank you very much for your help (and it came very fast as well, good community here).